# How to know which Windows Process has started / stopped which service

Tags: version-control, kernel-module, process-monitor, apimonitor

For example, want to know that sample.exe creates MyDriverService and runs Start / Stop to run myDriver.sys

I tried using Process Monitor, API Monitor but there was only information from Services.exe

Answer (score 0):

It's easy just on computer main screen at my computer logo click right click, then in menu select manage, you will see one new open window with computer information.
In left side menu in last you will find services and applications, click on it then click services you will find their all your computer running and stop services.
Other way you can only see the running services by right clicking on computer screen down window bar then open start task manger, one pop up window will open there will be information of your computer running application running process and many other useful information's 
Hope you will find it helpful